# How to parse nested objects in json using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, parsing, nested, retrofit

This is reddit/r/pic/.json data.
I want to parse preview object and extract image URL.

```
{
"preview": {
"images": [
  {
    "source": {
      "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/TIqBgNYhZaHMdHN61yUbFPDgDnsFCNkPi6Tb5p2Q-ac.png?s=9ee1ffdf902191de6be14972b7637866",
      "width": 772,
      "height": 762
    },
    "resolutions": [
      {
        "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/TIqBgNYhZaHMdHN61yUbFPDgDnsFCNkPi6Tb5p2Q-ac.png?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=108&amp;s=2d74b9538ff6495f651ce8575baf46b5",
        "width": 108,
        "height": 106
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
}
```

Comment: Have to created pojo classes for this

Comment: just give some example for that.

Comment: you can generate pojo classes from this link also http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: mainJsonObject.getJSONObject("preview").getJSONArray("images").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("source").getString("url")

Answer (score 0):

You can have `POJOs`for those fields.

Example:

**preview** here is an object however **images** is an array/list.

You create a source class like this

```
class Source {
    private String url;
    private int width;
    private int height;
}
```

you can also see that **resolutions** array uses same keys/fields as the source class, this becomes more convenient to address

```
class Images {
    private Source source;
    private List<Soutrce> resolutions;
}
```

assuming you have a reddit class for parsing response, your preview will be

```
class Preview {
    private List<Images> images;
    // .. and some more fields if any
}

class Reddit {
    // ...above fields eg: over_18 and approved_by from your example
    private Preview preview;    
}
```

so your image will be at `preview.images.get(0 /*position here*/).url;`